Trying to solve for a non-linear set of equations but encountering an error about nleqslv's data output
I am encountering this error:
Error in nleqslv(p_t = p0_t, FOC_t, jac = NULL, df = school_t) :
Argument 'x' cannot be converted to numeric!
This happens when I iteratively try to solve a set of non-linear equation. The code specific to my problem is:
for (k in 1:4000) { # For each market: T = 4000
     
      ### Creating data subset
      school_t <- subset(school, T == k) 
      
      ### Starting guess for price
      p0_t <- 1.50 * school_t$MC    
      
      ### Solving first order conditions using newton method
      Y <- nleqslv(p_t = p0_t, FOC_t, jac = NULL, df = school_t)
      
      p1_t <- Y$x                                 # Nleqslv stores solution as x
      s_t <- mktshare_t(p1_t, x_t, xi_t)
      s0_t <- rep(1 - sum(s_t), J)
      
      ### Storing price and market share data 
      price <- c(price, p1_t)
      share <- c(share, s_t)
      share_0 <- c(share_0, s0_t)
      
    }

The code is towards the bottom of the following code. This is the whole r file so everyone is able to replicate it:
# Setting seed = 123
set.seed(123)

# Defining market and product data
school <- expand_grid(T = 1:4000, J = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

school$jt <- paste(school$T, school$J, sep = "-")

# (i) Simulating exogenous product attributes for each (j, t) observation

  ## Product Quality (x)
  school$x <- runif(nrow(school), min = 0, max = 1)
  
  ## Unobserved Utility Effect (xi)
  school$xi <- rnorm(nrow(school), mean = 0, sd = 1)
  
  ## Cost effect (w)
  school$w <- runif(nrow(school), min = 0, max = 1)
  
  ## Product Ownership (firm)
  firm <- 1:2
  school$firm <- sample(firm, size = nrow(school), replace = TRUE)
  
  ## Marginal cost
  school$MC <- school$x + school$w
  
# (ii) Creating a market share function: s_t = s(p_t, x_t, xi_t)
  mktshare_t <- function (p_t, x_t, xi_t) {
  
  ## Mean utility vector in market t using the three J x 1 vectors
    ### (u_jt = \beta_1 + \beta_2 * x_j - \alpha * p_t + \xi_t)
  u <- - 1 + (1) * x_t - (1) * p_t + xi_t
  
  ## Estimating and returning market share
  return((exp(u)) / (1 + sum(exp(u))))
 
  }
  
    
# (iii) Estimating Nash-Equilibrium prices and market shares
    
    ## Creating a function to return first order conditions for each (f, t)
    FOC_t <- function (p_t, df) {
      
      ## Creating paramater vectors
      x_t <- df$x
      xi_t <- df$xi
      MC <- df$MC
      firm <- df$firm
      
      ### Market Share
      s <- mktshare_t(p_t, x_t, xi_t)
      
      ### Creating market specific index for firm
      y <- match(firm, unique(firm))
      
      # Aggregating each firm's market share
      agg <- as.numeric(tapply(s, y, sum))
      sf <- agg[y]
      
      markup <- 1 / (1 - sf)
      
      return(p_t - MC - markup)
      
    }
    
    ## Estimating market share and price for each market t and school j
    
      ### Empty matrix to contain market share and price
      share <- c()        # Inside market share
      share_0 <- c()      # Outside market share
      price <- c()
      
    for (k in 1:4000) { # For each market: T = 4000
     
      ### Creating data subset
      school_t <- subset(school, T == k) 
      
      ### Starting guess for price
      p0_t <- 1.50 * school_t$MC    
      
     ** ### Solving first order conditions using newton method
      Y <- nleqslv(p_t = p0_t, FOC_t, jac = NULL, df = school_t)**
      
      p1_t <- Y$x                                 # Nleqslv stores solution as x
      s_t <- mktshare_t(p1_t, x_t, xi_t)
      s0_t <- rep(1 - sum(s_t), J)
      
      ### Storing price and market share data 
      price <- c(price, p1_t)
      share <- c(share, s_t)
      share_0 <- c(share_0, s0_t)
      
    }
    
    
    

I will be super super gratefuk if anyone is able to help with this.
Thank you!
I tried the code I have posted and I expected three vectors - price, share and share_0 containing 24000 observations that have been optimised using nleqslv. While I have checked all the documentation for nleqslv and checked stack overflow for similar topics, I have not been able to resolve my issue.
